# Can multi platform app published Facebook OG story, link to AmazonStore when the app is not installed on Amazon devices

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, amazon-appstore, applinks

I am working on a multi platform app, availabe on Facebook, iOS, Android, and Amazon devices.

Facebook originally use Deep Linking to open iOS app or Android app when user clicked Open Graph story, and open iOS store or Google Play store when app is not installed.

However Deep Linking does not support Amazon Store on Amazon devices. Asked Facebook support team, their reply is "as designed", not supporting Amazon devices. And suggested to use App Links instead of Deep Linking.

After I put the meta data on the Facebook app page followed by App Links sample, and use Amazon store url as fall to web url, and turned Deep Links off in Facebook app. Click the link from Open Graph story when using Amazon devices, Facebook just open the app web page, and doesn't link to my app. I tried when app installed and not installed, definitely not working on Amazon devices.

I checked App Links website and searched on Google, but no mention about Amazon Devices and Amazon Store from Facebook using App Links.

Anyone know how to achieve App Links to Amazon devices? Or even this is achievable?

Thanks a lot.

```
<head>
<meta property="al:android:package" content="org.applinks" />
<meta property="al:android:url" content="applinks://docs" />
<meta property="al:android:app_name" content="App Links" />
<meta property="al:ios:url" content="applinks://docs" />
<meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="12345" />
<meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="App Links" />
<meta property="al:web:url"
content="**http://www.amazon.com/dp/AppID**" />
<!-- Other headers -->
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your app uses a different package name on the play store and the amazon app store, then you can add another al:android* section to allow deep linking to work if your app is installed on the device, but there's no support to open the Amazon store at this time.

```
<meta property="al:android" content="" />
<meta property="al:android:package" content="org.applinks" />
<meta property="al:android:url" content="applinks://docs" />
<meta property="al:android:app_name" content="App Links" />
<meta property="al:android" content="" />
<meta property="al:android:package" content="org.applinks.amazon" />
<meta property="al:android:url" content="applinks://docs" />
<meta property="al:android:app_name" content="App Links on Amazon" />
```